# In WinSCP can you use the * for upload path in filemask

Tags: c#, .net, winscp, winscp-net

I am trying to set the WinSCP filemask so that any file in a local directory is uploaded to a remote directory on a file by file basis, without including the local directory name, itself, in the remote directory. The following works:

```
TransferOperationResult tR;
tR = session.PutFiles(_localPath + "*", _remotePath);
```

but I'd like to use a filemask instead of the `+ "*"`.

```
// Upload files
TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
transferOptions.FileMask = "*";

TransferOperationResult tR;
tR = session.PutFiles(_localPath, _remotePath, false, transferOptions);
```

Is that possible? With either `*` or `*.*` filemask then the `_localPath` uploads all files in the directory but includes the local directory name in the remote directory as well.  I checked [WinSCP filemask](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask) and [TransferOptions](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_transferoptions) but I didn't see an easy way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep `_localPath + "*"` and set `TransferOptions.FileMask` on top of that.

Or even better, use [`RemotePath.Combine`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_remotepath_combine).

```
TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
// a sample filemask, so that it makes a sense to set the FileMask 
transferOptions.FileMask = "*>1H"; 

string sourcePath = RemotePath.Combine(_localPath, "*");
TransferOperationResult tR;
tR = session.PutFiles(sourcePath, _remotePath, false, transferOptions);
```

---

See a documentation of the [`localPath` parameter](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_putfiles#localpath):

> Full path to local file or directory to upload. Filename in the path can be replaced with Windows wildcard to select multiple files. To upload all files in a directory, use mask `*`.

So a value of the parameter must be `/foo/bar/*`.

The [`TransferOptions.FileMask`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_transferoptions#filemask) is an additional filter on top of the wildcard in `localPath` parameter.